# How to pass variables in Ajax.BeginFrom

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am new to C # and I need to spend in the following function ( PostFilure ) in js a string variable from C # . The problem is that the function returns some object and I don't understand where comes from. My code;

Index.cshtml;

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions {
    HttpMethod = "post", OnBegin = "PostOnBegin", OnFailure =
    "PostFailure", OnSuccess = "PostSuccess", OnComplete =
    "PostOnComplete" })) {...
```

anylib.js

```
 function PostFailure(message){

 }
```

the idea would be:

Index.cshtml;

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new
 AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", OnBegin = "PostOnBegin", OnFailure
 = "PostFailure(messaje,'hello')", OnSuccess
 = "PostSuccess", OnComplete = "PostOnComplete" }))
```

anylib.js

```
function PostFailure(message,x){

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this in your `OnSuccess` event handler method.

```
 function PostSuccess(ajaxContext) {
     //ajaxContext is the json representation of myModel returned from the server in Json(myModel);
     console.log(ajaxContext.MyReturnField1);
 }
```

The `OnFailure` handler will fire for anything other than a 200 ok http status. The normal value would be statusText and this would be something along the lines of "Internal Error Occurred on the server", for 500. However, be sure you are not receiving specialized objects for non-200 http codes that you should be looking for in which case the xhr result data could be anything.

```
function PostFailure(exception) {
     console.log(exception);
     console.log(exception.statusText);
     console.log(exception.MyUserFiendlyErrorMessage);
     $("#divError").html(exception.ClientExceptionPartiaViewHTML);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can add variable string from Index.cshtml to function PostFailure(exception,'hello') {} ?

Comment: You can't add a parameter to the event. That handler is interpreting what is sent back via an ajax call. You can add data to the payload of what is returned. Are you wanting to add a variable prior to the ajax call being submitted to the server or return a variable form the server when the call fails?